# How to fix 'UploadTask method OnComplete does not exist' error in Flutter Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StorageServisi {
  Reference _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  Future<String> gonderiResmiYukle(File resimDosyasi) async {
    UploadTask yuklemeYoneticisi =
        _storage.child("resimler/gonderiler/gonderi.jpg").putFile(resimDosyasi);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await yuklemeYoneticisi.onComplete;
    String yuklenenResimUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return yuklenenResimUrl;
  }
}
```

> Flutter - > UploadTask method OnComplete does not exists

Changed onComplete method in Firebase Storage usage. Can you help me how to run my code with the new update?

Answer (score 0):

This function uploads photo and get download url.   Change contentType as your content.

```
Future<String> uploadPhoto()async{

        try{

          String filename = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        
          
          Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("images").child('$filename.png');
          
          final UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putData(bytes!,
          SettableMetadata(
            contentType: "image/png"
          )
          );
          
          final TaskSnapshot downloadUrl = await uploadTask;
          final String attchurl = await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();

          return attchurl;

      }catch(e) {
        log(e.toString());

          print(e);
        }

        return "";

  }
```